# How can I write a Template.pm filter to generate PNG output from LaTeX source code?

Tags: perl, latex, png, template-toolkit

I am looking for a way of generating PNG images of equations from L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X source code embedded in templates. For example, given:

```
[% FILTER latex_display ]
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max && U(x,y) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} && p_x x + p_y y \leq I \\
&& x \geq 0, y \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
[% END %]
```

I would like to get the output:

```
<div class="latex display"><img src="equation.png" width="x" height="y"></div>
```

which should ultimately display as:

> [image: Consumer's Optimization Problem]

I am using [ttree](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.00/bin/ttree) to generate documents offline. I know about [Template::Plugin::Latex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::Latex) but that is geared towards producing actual documents out of L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X templates.

Any suggestions?

#### Update:

I appreciate the suggestions (and I have voted them up). However, they are no quite what I need. I would really appreciate a few pointers towards getting started with a Plugin or Filter for Template Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia does something similar to what you want. They use a program called [`texcv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texvc). Then you also have [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) which is more aimed at dynamic math rendering in web-pages.

`texcv` is according to the linked page written in OCaml however since the rest of Mediawiki is written in PHP I don't think you should have any problem with repurposing the program to use with Perl.

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look at [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/), [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/), or [mathjax](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/12/still-more-latex-on-web.html)

Answer (score 2):

> *I would really appreciate a few pointers towards getting started with a Plugin or Filter for Template Toolkit*

These docs on [`Template Toolkit`](http://template-toolkit.org) site should provide all necessary info to setup a plugin or filter:

- [Plugin provider module](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugins.html)
- [Base class for plugin filters](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Filter.html)

Once you have your L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X to PNG conversion sorted then you probably need to save it as a file using [redirect](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html#section_redirect_file_options_).  Example from POD:

```
[% PROCESS my/png/generator 
    FILTER redirect("images/logo.png", binmode=1) %]
```

Hope that helps.

/I3az/